# Pylance error that generic Type bounded to parent class but cannot assigned to child class

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, pylance

FloatBase is parent abstract class, and Bfloat16/Float32 is its child classes.
I want to show FloatFMA.fma() will return Bfloat16/Float32 by FloatFMA's argument respectively, so I used generic type bounded to parent class.
However, Pylance says that I cannot assign Bfloat16/Float32 to FloatBaseT.

```
from bf16 import * # here bf16 is package name
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from ..utils import utils as hwutil

FloatBaseT = TypeVar('FloatBaseT', bound='FloatBase')

class FloatFMA(Generic[FloatBaseT]):
    def __init__(self, a: FloatBaseT, b: FloatBaseT, c: FloatBaseT) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def fma(self) -> FloatBaseT:
        # bf16: alias to Bfloat16
        # fp32: alias to Float32
        bf16_input = isinstance(self.a, bf16) & isinstance(self.b, bf16) & isinstance(self.c, bf16)
        if bf16_input:
            self.a = self.a.bf16_to_fp32()
            self.b = self.b.bf16_to_fp32()
            self.c = self.c.bf16_to_fp32()

        ...

        # Compose BF16
        fma = fp32.compose(ret_sign, ret_exp, ret_mant)
        # If input is Bfloat16, fp32_to_bf16
        if bf16_input:
            fma = fma.fp32_to_bf16()
        return fma
```

Pylance says:

```
Expression of type "Bfloat16 | Float32" cannot be assigned to return type "FloatBaseT@FloatFMA"
  Type "Bfloat16 | Float32" cannot be assigned to type "FloatBaseT@FloatFMA"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) fma: Bfloat16 | Float32
```

What could be an issue? If I need more code to provide, I can do full code.